# Separating the linked list implementation from the malloc function

Tags: c, memory-management

I have been told to design a linked list module where the linked list functions will all be in one header file but the memory allocation(malloc) will not happen those modules. 
The memory allocation should ONLY happen in the main function. I am unable to figure it out. Do help me.

Comment: First, it would help to choose a language. The better solutions will differ between C and C++.

Comment: Is this homework? If so then tag it as such.

Comment: Firstly, its not a homework and secondly C is the language i am working on.

Answer (score 0):

In `main` you should allocate a sufficiently large amount of memory (A memory pool), in one go. Now in your module you need to manage (allocate and free) memory chunks from this pool, and not bother with `malloc`.

If you don't know about memory pool, read this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool.

However there is problem of fragmentation, which you need to tackle. In the steps below I use a bit array, to mark the free and allocated nodes.

Example-

- In `main` you allocate 50*sizeof(node) (50 depends on application)
- Now, you pass the pointer of allocated pool to your function.
- Keep a counter, to count number of allocated nodes, initialize it to 0
- Also keep a bit array, of size 50, initialized to 0 (all free)
- When allocating, check for overflow, iterate over the bit-array, to find first free node. If *j* th bit is 0, pass on the address of new node as Base + *j*(*sizeof node), and increment the counter. Set the *j* th bit to 1.
- When deallocating, simply decrement the counter, and set the corresponding bit to 0.

HTH

Comment: That's quite simple - just create a function `node* allocNode()` which uses logic in the example (above) for finding a free node, and returns the address of first free node. Also if the logic permits, you can get rid of addresses altogether, and just deal with offsets of node in the pool.

Answer (score 0):

that has been implemented already: look at `<sys/queue.h>` that's a header only linked list.

Comment: How do i pass a node to the functions defined in that header?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as an array of structures and link it by array index. That array can then be allocated in the `main` function. Note that you have to keep track of the number of entries you have in your list, as the list will be limited to the number of entries you allocate.